# Pivot a python list

Tags: python

Could anyone help me with code/commands that will pivot the following data in columns/rows i.e:

```
[('A', '1'),
 ('A', '2'),
 ('A', '3'),
 ('B', '4'),
 ('B', '5'),
 ('C', '6'),
 ('C', '7')]
```

into

```
[('A', 'B', 'C'),
('1', '4', '6'),
('2', '5', '7'),
('3', '', '')]
```

I'll separate the data using tabs so I can paste it into Excel.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*There must be a shorter & easier way, but this is what I did ([demo](http://tpcg.io/vUClXK)):*

```
a = [('A', '1'),
 ('A', '2'),
 ('A', '3'),
 ('B', '4'),
 ('B', '5'),
 ('C', '6'),
 ('C', '7')]


unique_keys = tuple(sorted(set(k for k,v in a)))
print(unique_keys)

values = tuple(sorted(v for k,v in a))
print(values)

ls = [unique_keys, ]
default = ''

# the sorted part allows me to iterate without checking which key I'm adding 
while len(a):
    tmp = []
    for uk in unique_keys:
        uk_added = False
        for k,v in a:
            if k == uk:
                tmp.append(v)
                a.remove((k,v))
                uk_added = True
                break
        if not uk_added:
            tmp.append(default)

    ls.append(tmp)

print(ls)
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the zombie post, but just solved this one myself as per python docs suggestion to use the following list comprehension:

```
>>> matrix = [
...     [1, 2, 3, 4],
...     [5, 6, 7, 8],
...     [9, 10, 11, 12],
... ]

>>> [[row[i] for row in matrix] for i in range(4)]

[[1, 5, 9], [2, 6, 10], [3, 7, 11], [4, 8, 12]]
```

**Python Docs:** [Data Structures: Nested List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions)

Hope this helps the next person to find this post =)